# Add prefix to each lines of file from other file

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I have two files named file1.txt and file2.txt, I'm trying to add the prefix to file2.txt from file1.txt in a manner **so I can pipe the results** to the next utility I'm using.

```
cat file1.txt

aa
bb
cc

cat file2.txt

site.com
site2.com
site3.com
```

Expected result will look like:

```
aa.site.com
aa.site2.com
aa.site3.com
bb.site.com
bb.site2.com
bb.site3.com
cc.site.com
cc.site2.com
cc.site3.com
```

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The easy part is that you can use `paste` to merge the lines of your files. Its `-d` option lets you choose a delimiter (here, a `.`).

The hard part here is the Cartesian product. Borrowing from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1620993/10488700), we can come up with a command like this:

```sh
paste -d '.' \
  <(sed -n "$(yes 'p;' | head -n $(wc -l <file2.txt) )" file1.txt) \
  <(cat $(yes 'file2.txt' | head -n $(wc -l <file1.txt)))
```

Where we:

- Combine `yes` and `head` to make a `sed` script that will print each line of `file1.txt` a number of times equal to the number of lines in `file2.txt`;
- Combine `yes` and `head` to make `cat` print `file2.txt` a number of times equal to the number of lines in `file1.txt`;
- Use `paste` to merge each pair of lines printed by the two process substitutions (`<(...)`), separated by a `.`.

Of course you can pipe the result into other commands.
Also, note that you can always pipe the output of commands, even if they are in a loop, as in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1393481/955970) you have. E.g. try

```sh
while ... do ... done <file | cat -
```

For convenience, you can define a function and make it available to your environment (e.g. defining it in your `.bashrc` if you use `bash`).
An example, here using loops to minimize the need for external tools:

```sh
function cart_prod () {
  while IFS= read -r line1; do
    while IFS= read -r line2; do
      printf '%s.%s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
    done <"$2"
  done <"$1"
}
```

Sample usage:

```sh
$ cart_prod file1.txt file2.txt | sort -r
cc.site.com
cc.site3.com
cc.site2.com
bb.site.com
bb.site3.com
bb.site2.com
aa.site.com
aa.site3.com
aa.site2.com
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line1; do while IFS= read -r line2; do echo "$line1.$line2"; done <file2.txt; done <file1.txt
```

or

```
join -j 64 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) -o 1.1,2.1 | sed 's/ /./'
```

Output:

```
aa.site.com
aa.site2.com
aa.site3.com
bb.site.com
bb.site2.com
bb.site3.com
cc.site.com
cc.site2.com
cc.site3.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Cyrus, it works as expected.